# calculate cluster centroid using kmeans

Tags: scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I want to calculate the centroid vector for a cluster with scikit-learn:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=1, random_state=0).fit(X)
```

If I set `n_cluster=1`, does this mean I calculate the mean of X?

For example, if there are three data points in X, and each data point has a 4d vector, `X=[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9]]`, so after I used kmeans to calculate the centroid vector, it will be `centroid_vect = [3,4,5,6]`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, exactly. The centroids are stored in `kmeans.cluster_centers_` **after** fitting the model.

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=1, random_state=0).fit([[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9]])

kmeans.cluster_centers_
#array([[3., 4., 5., 6.]])
```